# How do I access an outer collection itemsource property from an inner collection?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, collections, binding

I have two collections.

The 'OuterCollection' collection contains the 'InnerCollection' collection and a property called 'OuterProperty'. In my 'InnerCollection', it only contains one property called 'InnerProperty'.

Now my ViewModel contains 1 'OuterCollection'. And it's set to the data context of the control. So a very easy set up.

```
ViewModel
{
   OuterCollection;
}

OuterCollection
{
   InnerCollection;
   OuterProperty;
}

InnerCollection
{
   InnerProperty;
}
```

Now in the code, I want to be able to access my 'OuterProperty' from a trigger within the context of my 'InnerCollection' How can I do this? And if I can't do this, is there an alternative way to accomplish this?

Here's my attempt:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Path=OuterCollection}" />
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn>
                <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=InnerCollection}">
                            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <Image>
                                        <Image.Style>
                                            <Style TargetType="Image">
                                                <Style.Triggers>
                                                    <MultiDataTrigger>
                                                       <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                                          <Condition Binding="{Binding Path=InnerProperty}" Value="blah" />
                                                          <Condition Binding="{Binding Path=DataContext.OuterCollection.OuterProperty, RelativeSource ={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListView}}, Converter={StaticResource IsStringNullOrEmpty}}" Value="true" />
                                                       </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                                       <Setter Property="ToolTip">
                                                          <Setter.Value>
                                                             <TextBlock Text="test"/>
                                                          </Setter.Value>
                                                       </Setter>
                                                    </MultiDataTrigger>
                                                </Style.Triggers>
                                            </Style>
                                        </Image.Style>
                                    </Image>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        </ListBox>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn>
        </GridView>
     </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

Comment: You bind to `DataContext.OuterCollection.OuterProperty`. Unless the *DataContext* of the ListView (or one of its parent controls) is not set to the OuterCollection, the binding will not work. Why not bind to `ItemsSource.OuterProperty` instead? (Remark: I am not sure if `ItemsSource.OuterProperty` will parse. If not, keep the binding to the DataContext and set the DataContext property of the ListView explicitely to OuterCollection.)

Comment: ItemsSource.OuterProperty did not work, unfortunately. And I can't change the data context of the ListView, because I'm using mef injection for my view-viewmodel relationship. The view model is hooked up to the control. The outer and inner collections populate correctly. It's just a matter of accessing and outer control property while in the context of the inner collection.

Comment: I tried setting the Tag both on the ListView and the ListBox to the OuterCollection. Then I also tried binding the Tag on the ListBox directly to the OuterProperty, but unfortunately that didn't work either.. Rely on INotifyPropertyChanged.

Comment: Sorry, i did not see that you use GridViewColumns, in which case FindAncestor is not working, since GridViewColumns is not part of the visual tree. Need to substitute the binding with something else... hmm...

Comment: If i am not mistaken, the DataContext of the **ListBox** should have the respective element of the *OuterCollection* collection assigned. Let the ancestor of the binding be the **ListBox**, like: `{Binding Path=DataContext.OuterProperty, RelativeSource ={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListBox}} ...` (I write this based on the foggy memories from the back of my head, i hope it will work...)

Comment: I would rather call that "very sleepy eyes", otherwise i would have spotted the error earlier ;-)